# Center an animated element inline-block

Tags: css, animation, display

I want to center vertically the second span of my H1.

I've already tried to modify the `display: inline-block` to `display: flex`, but this makes me start my animation at the start of my container and not at the center.

I think the problem is related to the multiple different display assigned to the span's parents ?

**HTML**

```
<section class="container">
            <div id="description">
                <h1>
                    <span>
                        This element is good,</span>
                    <span>
                        But this one is not centered.
                    </span>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="other-div">
            </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    margin: auto 30px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    display: flex;
}

#description {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: white;
}

#description h1 span:first-child {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: "Croissant One";
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    color: white;
}

#description h1 span:nth-child(2) {
    font-family: "Croissant One";
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(255, 237, 36);
    padding: 0px 15px;
    border-right: 0.15em solid white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    animation: typing 2.5s steps(30),
    blink-caret 0.9s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
from {
    width: 0
}

to {
    width: 52%
}
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
50% {
    border-color: transparent;
}
}

#other-div {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Can you please help me ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for perfect centralize you're second span
and start you're animation from the center and not start
you need to change you're styles and style the second span with flex item style:

```
align-self: center;
```

and add the flex property to h1 for centralize you're span. and width property to execute you're animation correctly:

```
#description h1{
display: flex;
width: 100%;
flex-direction: column; 
}
```

I edit you're style and comment it:

```
    .container {
    margin: auto 30px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 1rem;
}

#description {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}

/* You need set style for H1 element to get width 100% and execute youre animation correctuly, change width value for test it! :) */
#description h1{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#description h1 span:first-child{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: "Croissant One";
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    color: white;
    /* with this property you can align your first span horizantally */
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

#description h1 span:nth-child(2){
    font-family: "Croissant One";
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    /* You don't need this properties */
    /* display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; */
    overflow: hidden;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(255, 237, 36);
    padding: 0px 15px;
    border-right: 0.15em solid white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    animation: typing 2.5s steps(30),
    blink-caret 0.9s step-end infinite;
    /* with this property start you're animatin from center */
    align-self: center;
}

@keyframes typing {
from {
    width: 0
}

to {
    width: 52%
}
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
50% {
    border-color: transparent;
}
}

#other-div {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```